# How to fetch data from a 2D array in perl row by row?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array named @array_of_boards and the data in it looks like this,
`[{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{3,4,5}]`.

How do I loop through this array to fetch data row by row since I have to insert them into a table.

```
ColA,ColB,ColC
1,2,3
4,5,6
3,4,5

my @array_of_boards=(0,0,0);
my @temp_array = (1,2,3);
push @array_of_boards,@temp_array
@temp_array = (4,5,6);
push @array_of_boards,@temp_array
@temp_array = (3,4,5);
push @array_of_boards,@temp_array
```

I tried using this,but it fails to allign the data properly.

```
foreach my $row (@array_of_boards){
    my ($ColA,$ColB,$ColC)=$row;
    ##followed by printing statements
}
```

Comment: I am facing an error while doing this

Comment: I am pushing an array (1,2,3) (for example) into @array_of_boards each time. Is the way I am accessing each row wrong?

Comment: You'll need to show the code where you create the array. It probably doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: Also, `{}` is the syntax for a hash reference. An array reference would be `[]`.

Comment: Have made changes in the code.. Thanks a ton.

Comment: You should have a look at [this](https://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html). In order to create arrays of arrays you should push the elements with [].

Comment: works, thank you so much.

Comment: @user3800888 https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
my @array_of_boards = (0, 0, 0);
my @temp_array = (1, 2, 3);
push(@array_of_boards, @temp_array);
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
my @array_of_boards = (0, 0, 0);
push(@array_of_boards, 1, 2, 3);
```

And produces an array that contains six elements, which you can see in the output from [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper):

```
$VAR1 = [
          0,
          0,
          0,
          1,
          2,
          3
        ];
```

Instead, each element of the outer array should be an array reference, like so:

```
my @array_of_boards = ([0, 0, 0]);
push(@array_of_boards, [1, 2, 3]);
```

This results in the following data structure:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ]
        ];
```

Which can then be accessed as intended:

```
for my $array_ref (@array_of_boards) {
    my @row = @$array_ref;
    ...
}
```